# Simple BiPAP Controller: low-pressure + high-flow

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, switches, relay, solenoid-valve

At this point I can't remember if my intent was to actually build a ventilator, although at the time I seem to remember a relative lack of posts on StackExchange pertaining to ventilator design, despite it being all over the news.

I think my goal with this post was in some way to contribute to open-sourcing ventilators. It turns out I did not know how complex a ventilator was, and as a result I discovered my basic design was missing a few parts although the basic functioning of it could potentially conform to the guidelines for pressure controlled ventilation (PCV) however missing a few parts thus making it most accurately a BiPAP machine. At this point the details aren't really all that important (and they are all in [the guidelines](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/879382/RMVS001_v4.pdf)), since I don't think I will ever build this thing. So anyway, my idea; here are some doodles I hope they are self explanatory:

ascii art schematic of the Party-Balloon BiPAP:

```
     (close-circuit when balloon is full)
          ....switch.................. 
          .    __\__                 .
          .   /     \            ____._____
          .  / party \          |Controller|
          .  |balloon|           ----.-----
          .  \       /               .
          .   \     /                .
          .    \_ _/                 .
          .     /_\             ............
          .     ||              .          .exhaust
regulator=T=====++=======++=====T==========/switch 
  _I_   solenoid         ||   solenoid  (open-circuit when exhaust flows)
 /   \   valve           ||    valve 
|     | (inhale)         ||   (exhale)
|     |                 (oo)
| air |                  \?/
|     |                   T patient
|_____|                  /\
```

controller logic table:

```
switch  switch      inhale      exhale 
party   exhaust     solenoid    solenoid
0       1           1 open      0 closed    done exhale: begin inhale
1       1           1 open      1 open      balloon full: begin exhale
1       0           0 closed    1 open      exhaling: stop air intake
0       0           0 closed    1 open      continue exhaling: air flowing
```

here's my new improved truth table:

```
                  ----controls----
State e b  next exhaust_s intake_s
0     0 0   1     open     closed
0     0 1   1     open     closed
0     1 0   0    closed     open  stay inhale phase
0     1 1   1     open     closed begin exhale phase
1     0 0   1     open     closed stay exhale phase
1     0 1   1     open     closed
1     1 0   0    closed     open  begin inhale phase
1     1 1   1     open     closed

State = 0 = inhale-phase, State = 1 = exhale-phase
exhaust flap: e = 1 = closed-flap, e = 0 = flowing-exhaust
balloon switch: b = 1 = balloon-full, b = 0 = not-full
```

...and associated logic diagram & karnaugh map (done in GIMP):

[image: logic diagram & karnaugh map]

...and my resulting digital logic / logic-gate circuit (Logisim):

[image: combinational logic]

So there, I came up with a very basic logic diagram. I'm not sure the rest of the idea is sound though; I took a lot of inspiration from Macgyver.

Comment: *how would you implement this on breadboard?* - begin with a circuit diagram.

Comment: How do you control the patient to synchronize their breathing with your machine?

Comment: *I think perhaps I might need a denouncer.* I'm going to leave that alone.

Comment: If you had cast this question as a generic digital design problem I would have been inclined to help, but designing medical devices comes with its own set of ethical considerations. Thinking that you can DIY a ventilator leads to situations where people ingest aquarium chemicals because some idiot on TV suggested that he had a feeling that it might help. Do your homework or leave it to the professionals.

Comment: Respectfully, I think the real professionals dealing with this crisis don't need this post to deal with it. So yeah, I think it's pretty harmless to remove coronavirus from your title. Perhaps I would clean up the title in general a bit, you can add tags on the question space instead of the title.

Comment: And this is exactly the problem. You said you had a link to make "N95 masks" but then admitted that success depends on materials used. So you give one to a healthcare worker and say "Here is an N95 mask" that person will take personal risks that should only be made if they had a **real** N95 mask. If you want to build some gadget, fine, just don't call it a ventilator or a respirator.

Comment: If I want to buy an appropriate balloon, how do I know if it is a "standard party balloon"? Who wrote the standard and where can I get a copy of it? Is there any danger to the patient if my balloon doesn't meet this standard? Don't say standard if you mean "the one I happen to have on hand".

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a link-only answer, so it may well be downvoted and/or removed.

[Here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/874279/RMVS001_Rapidly_Manufactured_Ventilator_Specification__PDF.pdf) is a set of specifications for makeshift systems that might be acceptable for emergency short term use, according to the UK government. Note the mandatory safety devices, overpressure and a whole bunch of other things will cause **more damage** (including instant death) than help.

The control is not really a difficult project. Keeping it from killing the patient if the slightest thing goes wrong is the issue. Not to mention the issues with intubation.

In my estimation this is not a very suitable DIY project.

[Here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/universal-service/pdf_reader?spm=a3c0i.14138300.8102420620.dreadnow.6df3647ffnTwTx&cdnorigin=video-intl&pdf=Read%20Online-Handbook%20of%20COVID-19%20Prevention%20and%20Treatment.pdf) is a set of professional treatment standards put forward as good practice by the Jack Ma Foundation and Zhejiang University School of Medicine. Parts of it may be useful.

Comment: They work fine for me from the links above. Maybe they're blocked wherever you are.

Comment: This article was just published on Hackaday, might be an interesting addition: https://hackaday.com/2020/03/25/ventilators-101-what-they-do-and-how-they-work/

Comment: @WesleyLee Good article.